# Opendaylight Replicate Config Tree

Tags: akka, openstack, akka-cluster, opendaylight, akka-persistence

We are using ODL (Opendaylight) Nitrogen version. We are exploring options to support cluster (local and geo-redundant) with Nitrogen version. We want to know whether it is possible to replicate only "Config" data tree across various nodes in the cluster and avoid replicating "Operational" tree, to minimize bandwidth usage across WAN.

Answer (score 2):

The data tree is subdivided into shards with a config and operational component created for each and there's no way (currently) to disable replication for just  the operational shard component. Now if the config and operational data were in different yang modules then separate shards for each could be configured with config data shard replicated and the operational data shard non-replicated.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Is it possible to have custom implementation that can do this. If yes, do we need to check akka?

Comment: shards can be configured via the module-shards.conf file. Please refer to the on-line release documentation.